# Is there a useful distinction between the DIY and the telescope-making tags? Should they be somehow merged?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-tag, tagging, retagging

[telescope-making](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/telescope-making) has **16** questions starting from 2015

[diy](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diy) has <s>3</s> **4** questions starting from 2014. I just added one that mentions a Raspbery Pi project.

*Neither tag* has any usage guidance!

A quick check shows for example:

- [DIY telescope to observe nebulae](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/43843/7982) has neither tag
- [Are there home-brew photometers for amateur observing of variable stars and are they widely used?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34492/7982) has neither tag
- [Which type of telescope should I make?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/2212/7982) doesn't have `telescope-making`

**Question:** What is *or should be* the distinction between the diy tag and telescope-making tags? Before any endeavor to adjust tagging on old questions let's first decide how these two tags are distinct and in which cases each tag applies.

Comment: Maybe one should be made a synonym of another.

Comment: telescope-making is always DIY but DIY isn't always telescope-making?